# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress, blogger

I'm trying to move a blog from blogger to wordpress using a plugin with the code below. Here's the error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_STRING in /home/content/[HIDE]/wpbeginner-blogger.php on line 8

The code is :

```
  {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww8980\viewh7500\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 <?php\
 global $wpdb;\
 $old_url = $_GET['q'];\
 if ($old_url != "") \{\
   $permalink = explode("blogspot.ca", $old_url);\
   $q = "SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ".\
        "ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) WHERE ".\
        "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='blogger_permalink' AND ".\
        "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value='$permalink[1]'";\
  $new_url = $wpdb->get_var($q)? $wpdb->get_var($q) : "/";\
  header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");\
  header("Location: $new_url");\
 \}\
?>\
\
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You have to save your code as plain text, that looks like rich text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have used a text editer with rich text formatting. Try this:

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $old_url = $_GET['q'];
 if ($old_url != "") {
   $permalink = explode("blogspot.ca", $old_url);
   $q = "SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ".
        "ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) WHERE ".
        "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='blogger_permalink' AND ".
        "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value='$permalink[1]'";
  $new_url = $wpdb->get_var($q)? $wpdb->get_var($q) : "/";
  header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: $new_url");
 }
?>
```

Make sure you save it using a PLAIN TEXT EDITOR. I recommend [Notepad ++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Yeah no problem, just make sure you always use a plain text editor and this won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

`global $varname` is only valid inside a function.

That aside, what's with all the backslashes? It's possible they're the cause of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

use `fraise` software in `MAC` and remove the

```
`{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540
 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
 {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
 \margl1440\margr1440\vieww8980\viewh7500\viewkind0\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 `
```

text. Also all slashes as well . It clearly indicates that you used `text editor` of mac. It adds all this text to all files default when you create any file other than text file.